# Visual Studio 2015 SSDT 17.1 report designer issue

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

Lately, I have installed SSDT on my Visual Studio, and find out that I cannot do anything in the designer window.

The first - when I create a new report file (.rdl), it comes with 8 cells, instead of working body area of the report.

And second - I cannot drag any tools from the toolbox. When I drag, the mouse cursor turns to be a crossed circle (not available sign).

Any ideas, what it can be? I have reinstalled Visual Studio and components several times, with different scenarios. Nothing helps.

My platform is:
Windows 10 Home 64-bit,
SQL Server 2016 Std 64-bit (Database and Reporting Services),
SSDT 17.1,
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 3)

P.S: screenshot is attached
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your entire windows is covered by the parameter layout pane. So it looks something like this.

See you see the thick bar above the groups pane (just over halfway down)

[image]

**Drag that up and you'll see you report layout pane.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Probably this happens because of high screen resolution and Windows scaling issues. But, anyway - you saved me. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Those 8 cells for the input parameters, you can't place the toolbox items directly.

Right click on any of the cell -> **Add Parameter** -> **General** -> Select any **Data Type** from the dropdownlist to create the parameter.

Also in the **Name** and **Prompt** box provide valid details to show the input parameter details. Also you can Delete Row or Delete column by right click on the cell.

In the **Report Data**, you can add the **Datasets** for the input parameters (in case if it is dropdownlist) and for the body of the report.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But by default, .rdl should start with blank report body, where I can drag objects (table, textBox, shapes). I can create dataSource, dataSets, Parameters. I can also delete and add rows and columns to input parameter fields. But I cannot design my report. Even if I drag toolbox items to the area below input parameters section, it does not work. As there is no working area, only grey background.

Comment: Can you able to add the `Datasets` in the `Report Data` ?

Comment: Yes, I can add data source, data sets, parameters. I just cannot work in design view. Even if I create report in a wizard, with all data, groups, header, footer - it runs and shows me my report in preview mode. But in design view it's still just 8 cells of input parameter.